# The term 'set-variable' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I'm running Windows 10 and uninstalled a local copy of an instance of SQL Server which broke my Powershell.
When I load up ISE I get:

```
The term 'set-variable' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file,
or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:0 char:0
```

I have reinstalled SQL Server but....

Now not even Write-Host works, I checked my paths and they all check out.

Does anyone know how to fix, I can't find anything that points me to the solution.

Comment: Did you "Install-Module -Name SqlServer"? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/powershell/download-sql-server-ps-module?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Write-Host isn't working? Is this only in the ISE?

Comment: I get Install-Module is not recognised and it happens in both console and ise

Comment: Did your powershell directory get wiped?  Can you use `Import-Module`?

Comment: Check your system's environment variables. Chances are the path to your PowerShell folder was removed from the Path and/or PSModulePath variable.

Comment: Try installing the latest version and see if that corrects your issue https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-windows-powershell?view=powershell-6

Comment: Import-Module alone doesn't error but Import-Module SQLServer returns a long error, Import-Module SQLPS returns less errors

Comment: I verified the directories in my PSModulePath to make sure they are still there

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean - Tried that but told me that it wasn't built for my operating system

Comment: Try reinstalling Powershell [this way](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/reinstall-powershell/9012f88a-e154-4fa1-a556-763120508ce1)

Comment: @Theo gave it a go but it didn't work.

Comment: You could try a system restore from before the point where you uninstalled the local copy of an instance of SQL Server and take it from there.

Comment: All, thanks for taking the time to reply. In the end, I asked my IT team to rebuild my user profile on the laptop. Once it booted into my newly made profile everything was as it should be.